# When I close Nautilus, copy operation gets cancelled

Tags: nautilus, 18.04, copy

In Windows, If I copy-paste and then close the file explorer while the operation is running, the copy operation continues.

But in Ubuntu 18.04 when I close the file explorer (Nautilus), the copy operation gets cancelled.

How can I continue copying while I close Nautilus.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I restore the file progress dialog after closing it?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/233295/how-do-i-restore-the-file-progress-dialog-after-closing-it)

Comment: I suggest looking for another file manager. I know Dolphin handles this well.

Comment: I read the attached question. It actually confused me a bit more. In my case I know it cancelled and I want a solution so that it does not cancel. Can you please check in your machine whether it behaves the same way as mine?

Comment: I think the running process (Copy) is dependent on the Nautilus process. Just like when I close the terminal, all the commands are cancelled. The attached question suggests "You could be using a file browser that is written to cancel copy operations when the parent browsing window closes". I do not think any developer will waste their time to make the users life difficult.

Comment: I cannot reproduce this issue. When I copy a large file and close nautilus, the copy continues, and a notification '1 file operation active' appears. Reopening a nautilus window shows the progress "icon". Killing nautilus with "killall nautilus" indeed stops nautilus and aborts the copy operation. This is Ubuntu 18.04. @Kennedy Baird: not a duplicate because nautilus handles this different now than five years ago.

Comment: I think i missed the notification part. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @vanadium: The notification appears to be the answer to this question according to OP's comment. Could you please write one based on your comment? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check carefully if the file operation is really aborted, because that is not normal behaviour. Also in Ubuntu, the normal behaviour is for a file operation to continue when you close a nautilus window (either by the close button, or the hotkeys ctrl+w to close a single window, or ctrl+q to close all windows: "close the application").

Only when nautilus is fully terminated will a file operation be aborted. You can reproduce that by starting a large file operation, and then issuing the command "killall nautilus" in the terminal. This fully closes the nautilus process down, and with it ongoing file operations. When, however, you close windows or quit nautilus using the graphical user interface or standard hotkeys, nautilus remains active in the background.